# Ansible - How to patch systems in an order and based on the operating system?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have [dynmaic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) which has 10 nodes. 8 of them are RedHat and 2 of them are Ubuntu. The hosts are in random order.

I want to write a playbook so that it will patch the Ubuntu node at last after all the RedHat node are patched first. Instead of manipulating the inventory, how can I write a playbook for it?

I have written a playbook but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Unfortunately there no information about your inventory, the structure, groups, etc., ...

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look into [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) and the following minimal example playbooks options.

**1.)**

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Upgrade all packages
    ansible.builtin.dnf:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
    when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"

  - name: Update all packages to their latest version
    ansible.builtin.apt:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
    when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
```

**Documentation**

- [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)
- [`dnf` module – Manages packages with the dnf package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html#examples)
- [`apt` module – Manages apt-packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#examples)

**2.)**

Depending if [groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) are used

```yaml
---
- name: Update RedHat-based systems
  hosts: redhat
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Upgrade all packages
    ansible.builtin.dnf:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
  
- name: Update Debian-based systems
  hosts: ubuntu
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Upgrade all packages
    ansible.builtin.dnf:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
```

**Documentation**

- [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups)
- [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution)

**3.)**

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Include task list in play
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: redhat_updates.yml

  - name: Include task list in play
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: ubuntu_updates.yml
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Include task list in play
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "{{ ansible_facts['os_family'] }}.yaml"

  - name: Include task list in play
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "{{ ansible_facts['os_family'] }}.yaml"
```

**Documentation**

- [`import_tasks` module – Import a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html)
- [`include_tasks` module – Dynamically include a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html)
- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)

---

... and many more options to structure the upgrade process.